# Find First missing number in Set

Tags: java, collections

I need to find the **first missing number** from a HashSet, for example:

```
Set<Integer> h = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10));
```

In this example if we are iterating for the first time we shold get `int freeNumber = 5;`

Obviously I can sort and iterate with while loop until I find a missing number.
But it seems like not an optimized or elegant way of doing this operation.

```
int i = 1;
for (Integer number : allFileNumbers) {
    if(number != i) {
        missing = number;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: So your problem is "Given a `Set<Integer>`, find the smallest integer which is not contained in the set"?

Comment: There is other sets in Java. `TreeSet` have its values sorted.

Comment: As does `LinkedHashSet`, provided that the insertion of elements proceeds in sorted order (which is the case in the example).

Comment: how is this unclear is beyond me... may be someone can help me, but Im voting to re-open. +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea...

```
Set<Integer> h = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10));
Set<Integer> k = IntStream.rangeClosed(Collections.min(h),Collections.max(h)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
k.removeAll(h);
System.out.println(k.stream().findFirst().orElse(-1));
```

Answer (score 3):

The question title indicates that the solution should not depend on the implementation of `Set` used. In that case, iterating on the values of the `Set` is not your best option: `HashSet` for instance does not guarantee an iteration following insertion order or natural order.

Your best option is to iterate on integers and check their existence in the set. It is a straightforward approach, and will run in `O(k*p)` where `k` is the smallest value not in the set and `p` is the cost of calling `Set.contains()`. If your set has `O(1)` read access, then you get a `O(k)` complexity algorithm, which is linear.

Example:

```
public int findFirstNotInSet(Set<Integer> values) {
    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        if (!values.contains(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    // handle edge case for Integer.MAX_VALUE here
}
```

If you can make more assumptions on the values in the set (range, number of missing values,...) then you can probably speed this algorithm up.

Comment: If set has no missing value, that's returns `max number of set + 1` . I think we have to care of this check. Your method will return a forex :  `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)` for this -> result is `4`. So program will understand arrays like `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5 )` or more elements after 5. So we might check setSize in for loop if ends of set  I  think .

Comment: If the set contains `{1, 2, 3}`, then the first missing element in the set is `4`. I would think that this is precisely what the user expects to see.

Comment: But if we consider numbers entirely outside the set’s contents, perhaps, if the set contains `{1, 2, 3}`, the first missing element is zero. Also, reporting `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as missing without actually checking, doesn’t look right to me. With the current OpenJDK implementation you may never get that far, but it’s not future-proof…

Comment: That's true. It's an edge case that the user should handle, depending on the problem. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a `TreeSet`, or any `NavigableSet` in general, you can use a variant of *Binary Search* to find the first missing value:

```
static Integer firstMissing(NavigableSet<Integer> set) {
    if(set.size() <= 1) return null;
    Integer first = set.first(), last = set.last();
    if(set.size() == last - first + 1) return null; // no gaps at all
    while(true) {
        int middle = (first+last)>>>1;
        NavigableSet<Integer> sub = set.headSet(middle, false);
        if(sub.size() < middle - first) {// gap before middle
            set = sub;
            last = sub.last();
        }
        else {
            set = set.tailSet(middle, true);
            first = set.first();
            if(first != middle) return middle;
        }
    }
}
```

to be called like

```
NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
System.out.println(firstMissing(set));
```

First, since a `Set` doesn’t contain duplicates, we can use the minimum and maximum number to calculate which size a set of consecutive numbers should have. If the set has that size, we know that there are no gaps and can return immediately. Otherwise, we calculate the middle number and split the set into halves. For the first half set, we can do the same test to determine whether it has a gap, to proceed only with that half set to find the first gap. Otherwise, we take the second half, already knowing that there must be a gap. The search is over when that set doesn’t contain our middle number.

If you have an arbitrary `Set`, without a guaranteed order, there is no best way to do it, as every approach works good for certain input, but worse for other.

- You may simply copy the set to a `TreeSet` using `new TreeSet<>(set)` and use the method above
- you may loop over the number range, to test for the presence, then the absence of numbers

  ```
      static Integer firstMissing(Set<Integer> set) {
          if(set.size() <= 1) return null;
          Integer firstPresent = null, firstAbsent = null;
          for(int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE; firstPresent == null; i++)
              if(set.contains(i)) firstPresent = i;
          for(int i = firstPresent+1; firstAbsent == null; i++)
              if(!set.contains(i)) firstAbsent = i;
          return firstAbsent-firstPresent == set.size()? null: firstAbsent;
      }
  ```

  The loop conditions take advantage of the pre-test which ensures that there are at least two numbers in the set.

  The obvious problem is the large number range, we have to probe. If we know that all numbers are positive, we may replace `Integer.MIN_VALUE` with zero.
- you may loop over the set’s content, to record all encountered values in a searchable data structure. This is similar to the copying approach above, but e.g., if all numbers are positive, you may use the following test:

  ```
      static Integer firstMissing(Set<Integer> set) {
          if(set.size() <= 1) return null;
          BitSet bs = new BitSet();
          set.forEach(bs::set);
          int firstPresent = bs.nextSetBit(0), firstAbsent = bs.nextClearBit(firstPresent);
          return firstAbsent-firstPresent == set.size()? null: firstAbsent;
      }
  ```

  It works much better than `TreeSet` if there are only a few numbers missing or none at all, but much worse, if the values are really sparse.

Comment: before reading your answer I thought about `private static Integer firstMissing(Set<Integer> set) {
        int min = Collections.min(set);
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(set.size());
        set.forEach(bitSet::set);
        int firstHole = bitSet.nextClearBit(min);
        return firstHole > set.size() ? null : firstHole;
    }` but you already did... 1+

Answer (score 2):

You can found with stream I think. This will be like that  ;

```
Set<Integer> h = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10));

    h.stream().anyMatch(isMissed -> {
        if (!h.contains(isMissed + 1)) {
            System.out.println(isMissed + 1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Iteration on a `HashSet` is not guaranteed to follow order of insertion. In your example it might begin with `10`, and you will think that it is your result (since `11` is not contained in the set).

Comment: You are right. I missed this point, There will be a linkedHashSet to get right value in all time. Thanks for your attention. I updated to linkedHashset

Comment: What if integers are not inserted into the set in order?

Comment: Should be add in order. Questions related to ordered list i think

Comment: What is use of writing a method that always return true instead of finding missing number that can be newly added by questioner(true, Collection used determines encounter order of stream)