# Java generate and track small reusable unique numbers for business use cases

Tags: java, integer, set, uniqueidentifier

For inventory management we use a key/id called **item number**

- It is a consecutive number starting from `1`
- It must be unique
- The datatype is `int`
- It is not a database key
- It should get reused after deletion
- We want to keep it small, so customers may enter the number by hand (e.g. the barcode scanner fails or the item label is damaged)

### Current situation

- Currently we keep track of that number in the database.
- On each system (re-)start the highest currently used number is determined and used as a new starting point for every new number we need to generate
- if the next number is not free, we just skip it and continue until we find a free one (this check is rather expensive since a query to the db is made; however most of the time the numbers are not in use)
- the method responsible for the number generation is `serialized` for concurrent use

**Problem 1:** We are not able to reuse any item numbers after they have been deleted

**Problem 2:** Importing data from other sources

- items from foreign systems have their own item number which we need to keep (except if the item number is used in the current system, then a new item number is generated instead)
- these item numbers can have a much higher value as those in the current system
  => this leads to big gaps; after the next system start all new item numbers start from the highest number (!)

### Required change

- As part of system start-up we need to obtain the list of item numbers currently in use; I guess `SELECT`ing just that one column and storing it in a `Set` should be ok; the required size for that data structure would be approximately 400 KB (a set of 100.000 ids of type `int`)
- This set must then be consulted to find the next minimal number which is not contained in that set; that access needs to be serialized or handled in a concurrent matter (i.e. no two threads are allowed to receive the same number)
- I've found a trivial approach on how to obtain the next free number here: [Find First missing number in Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093599/find-first-missing-number-in-set/52094551)
- the set and the database must be kept in sync about which numbers are used and which numbers are free; i.e. I could first test the set until I find a free number, and then test in the database; if not free why-so-ever insert in set and repeat ...

### Questions

- Does this approach sound reasonable?
- Are you familiar with (standard) libraries which support implementing that kind of number generation?

Comment: The requirement about eager number reuse feels overcomplicated. How frequent are the numbers obsoleted? How many active numbers do you have at any given time? If it's 10k numbers than loosing a few only results in one extra digit that has to be entered.